# Distance in linkedgeodata with sparql

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, linked-data, sparqlwrapper, geosparql

I need to calculate distance between two points like this:

```
 Prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 Prefix ogc: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
 Prefix geom: <http://geovocab.org/geometry#>
 Prefix lgdo: <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/>

 Select distinct ?label ?uri ?geo
   { 
        ?uri rdf:type <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/Hotel>;
           geom:geometry [ ogc:asWKT ?geo ] .

        ?uri rdfs:label ?label

        Filter (
            bif:st_intersect (?geo, bif:st_point (13.3517,38.12407), 0.25) 
            ) .

   } LIMIT 1000
```

The problem is that it seems to give wrong [results](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org&query=+Prefix+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A+Prefix+ogc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Font%2Fgeosparql%23%3E%0D%0A+Prefix+geom%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fgeovocab.org%2Fgeometry%23%3E%0D%0A+Prefix+lgdo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A+Select+distinct+%3Flabel+%3Furi+%3Fgeo%0D%0A+++%7B+%0D%0A++++++++%3Furi+rdf%3Atype+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2FHotel%3E%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++geom%3Ageometry+%5B+ogc%3AasWKT+%3Fgeo+%5D+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++++++++%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel%0D%0A%0D%0A++++++++Filter+%28%0D%0A++++++++++++bif%3Ast_intersects+%28%3Fgeo%2C+bif%3Ast_point+%2813.3517%2C38.12407%29%2C+0.25%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++%29+.%0D%0A%0D%0A+++%7D+LIMIT+1000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on):
take for example this point (13.3517,38.12407) and one of the result is "Kafara Hotel". If you check its [geometry](http://linkedgeodata.org/page/geometry/way35556488), you can see that the distance is far away to 250m.

How can i get near places between that point and points around 250 meters?

Comment: It seems that the distances are far away to 250 metres for all three objects: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC1g8.png . Possibly '0.25' means '0.25 degree'?

Comment: it seems a problem of st_intersect.
Works with bif:st_intersects (?geo, bif:st_point (%s,%s), 0.25) = 1 but I do know why

Comment: I have supposed it was just a mistype and test with `bif:st_intersects`. Of course, `bif:st_intersects` works, but the problem is the same. These objects are too far away.

Comment: From [here](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtGeoSPARQLEnhancementDocs#Virtuoso%20Geo%20Spatial%20geometry%20functions): "Current version [of `st_intersects`] is not complete and does not support arcs of all sorts and rings of polygons, this is fixed in the next release".